# Why c++ compiler gives error when using `std::max()` function for two different type of numeric variable

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, max

Is there any reason that c++ compiler gives error when using two different numeric variable types in `std::max()` function? (e.g. `int` and `long`).

I mean something like: *"Sometimes we have this problem when using `std::max()` function for two different numeric variable types, so the compiler gives error to prevent this problem".*

Comment: the compiler can't know how to cast int -> long or long -> int

Comment: It's better to get a hard error rather than an implicit cast and then some strange behaviour happens that you can't explain.

Comment: @alon But I don't think there would be any problem when comparing two different numeric variable types, e.g. `(long)a > (int)b`.

Comment: @DeiDei Yeah I want to know what are those strange behaviors that I can't explain!

Comment: @Ali But `std::max` doesn't just perform a comparison: it evaluates to the result. Which result should you get for `(long)a > (int)b`, and what should its type be?

Comment: @alon -- the compiler doesn't know how to **convert** those types (although it most certainly does); a **cast** is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler produces an error because it cannot perform type deduction for the template argument of `std::max`. This is how `std::max` template is declared: the same type (template parameter) is used for both arguments. If the arguments have different types, the deduction becomes ambiguous.

If you work around the deduction ambiguity by supplying the template argument explicitly, you will be able to use different types as `std::max` arguments

```
std::max(1, 2.0); // Error
std::max<double>(1, 2.0); // OK
```

The reason why `std::max` insists on using a common type for its arguments (instead of using two independent types) is described in @bolov's answer: the function actually wants to return a *reference* to the maximum value.

Comment: actually the second form is not completely ok. Yes, it compiles but it returns a reference to a temporary that will expire at the end of the full expression (if the max value is a converted argument).

Comment: @bolov: Well, it is potentially *dangerous*, but it is OK. This is like a known peculiarity of `std::max`, something to be aware of.

Comment: @bolov unless you initialise another reference from it (why would you do that?) you're fine. This is no different than with the first example; your literals initialise temporaries in any case.

Comment: *This is like a known peculiarity of `std::max`* - not very well known, this is the first time I'd heard of it.

Comment: It's not peculiar in the least.

Answer (score 3):

`std::max` returns a reference to the argument that has the maximum value. The main reason it is this way is because it is a generic function and as such it can be used with types expensive to copy. Also you might actually need just a reference to the object, instead a copy of it.

And because it returns a reference to a argument, all arguments must be of the same type.

Comment: they don't need to be the same type

Comment: @oblivion yes they do

Comment: @AnT Ah yeah I mixed them

Comment: I don't think the reference aspect is terribly important. Even if the function returned by value, you'd need to pick one return type.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit agree

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to the question is that it's because `std::min` and `std::max` take only one template parameter that defines the types of both arguments. If/when you try to pass arguments of different types, the compiler can't decide which of those two types to use for the template argument, so the code is ambiguous. As originally defined in C++98, `std::min` and `std::max` had signatures like these (C++03, §[lib.alg.min.max]):

```
template<class T> const T& min(const T& a, const T& b);

template<class T, class Compare>
const T& min(const T& a, const T& b, Compare comp);

template<class T> const T& max(const T& a, const T& b);

template<class T, class Compare>
const T& max(const T& a, const T& b, Compare comp);
```

So the basic idea here is that the function receives two objects by reference, and returns a reference to one of those objects. If it received objects of two different types, it wouldn't be able to return a reference to an input object because one of the objects would necessarily be of a different type than it was returning (so @bolov is correct about that part, but I don't think it's really the whole story).

With a modern compiler/standard library, if you don't might dealing with values instead of references, you could pretty easily write code on this general order:

```
template <class T, class U>
std::common_type<T, U> min(T const &a, U const &b) { 
    return b < a ? b : a;
}

template <class T, class U>
std::common_type<T, U> max(T const &a, U const &b) { 
    return a < b ? b : a;
}
```

That makes it pretty easy to deal with your case of passing an `int` and a `long` (or other pairs of types, as long as `std::common_type` can deduce some common type for them, and `a<b` is defined for objects of the two types.

But, in 1998, even if `std::common_type` had been available so it was easy to do, that solution probably wouldn't have been accepted (and as we'll see, it's still open to some question whether it's a great idea)--at the time, many people still thought in terms of lots of inheritance, so it was (more or less) taken for granted that you'd frequently use it in situations where both arguments were really of some derived type, something on this general order:

```
class Base { 
// ...
    virtual bool operator<(Base const &other);
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
    // ...
};
class Derived2 : public Base {
    // ...
};

Derived1 d1;
Derived2 d2;

Base &b = std::max(d1, d2);
```

In this case, the version above that returns a value instead of returning a reference would cause a serious problem. `common_type<Derived1, Derived2>` is going to be `Base`, so we'd end up slicing the argument to create an object of type `Base`, and returning that. This would rarely provide desirable behavior (and in some cases, such as if `Base` were an abstract base class, it wouldn't even compile).

There's one other point that's probably worth noting: even when applied in a seemingly simple situation, `std::common_type` can produce results you might not expect. For example, let's consider calling the template defined above like:

```
auto x = min(-1, 1u);
```

That leaves us with an obvious question: what type will `x` be?

Even though we've passed it an `int` and an `unsigned`, the type of the result is (at least potentially) neither `int` or `unsigned` (e.g., quite possibly `long long`)!